# Axiomatization of Topology

Tags: general-topology

There are some important concepts ( kind of structure ) that a topology wants to capture on a set, namely :

1- Nets of points on that set and convergence ( Limit points, etc ).

2- "Openness" , Neighbourhoods and Interior.

3- "Closedness" and Closure

4- Continuous functions acting on that set and Homeomorphisms

5- Compactness

6 - Density, Separability and Connectedness
.

P.S : Is there any other major concept i'm forgetting ?

I'm wondering if we can choose ANY of those concepts as a base for our axiomatization , even if it is gonna be a bit wierd,and then develop all the other concepts starting from those, or if the mentioned concepts are not equally as fundamental.

From example, i know we can start from 1,any of the concepts in 2,3 and even 4 ( topologies in terms of their algebras of real-valued continuous functions ).

But what about 5 and 6 ? Are they equally as fundamental as the others ? Could we choose those concepts as a base for our axiomatization and develop all the others from them ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It's not true that you can start from 4. Not all topological spaces have enough real-valued functions. The spaces that most obviously can be so reconstructed are the compact Hausdorff spaces, via Gelfand duality. Neighborhoods, on the other hand, is a separate concept from openness.

Comment: I would include separation in the list -- regular, normal, etc.

Comment: The trivial topology, $\{X,\varnothing\}$ makes $X$ compact, separable, and connected, so with 5 and 6 it seems you will never say anything non-trivial ... unless I'm misunderstanding the question...

Comment: To refine the comment about compactness, it's not the case that topologies can be characterized in terms of their compact sets. This is clear from the consideration of finite spaces, in which all subsets are compact. Similarly, connectedness can't distinguish a discrete space from a totally disconnected non-discrete space such as $\mathbf{Q}$. I'm still not sure what to say about the collection of dense subsets determining the topology.

Comment: Density of a subset is a global property. I don't believe you can distinguish between $\mathbb R$ and the non-Hausdorff $\mathbb R$ with "two zero points" by looking at dense sets?

Comment: @KevinArlin Would it be possible to elaborate on the comment "not all topological spaces have enough real-valued functions [to start from 4]"? (E.g. via a reference.) I guess would non-commutative $C^*$ algebras be what you have in mind? I think the comment answers a question I had so I'm curious to learn more.

Comment: @Chill2Macht No, a non-commutative algebra doesn’t come from a topological space at all. The point was that topological spaces like the indiscrete spaces with more than one point may have no non-constant real-valued functions on them, so there’s no way to get any information about the space from its algebra of real valued functions.